# Irregularly Intertwined Linear Recursions: Other References?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series, degree-sequence, algebraic-dynamics

I was wondering if anyone had run across the following notion of intertwined linear recursions. I'm looking for references, or even a standard name. (I know one source, which is the genesis of this question, and which I'll explain at the end.)

Let $A^{(1)},A^{(2)},\ldots,A^{(k)}$ be a finite list of (integer-valued) linear recursions, and let
$$ \nu : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,k\} $$
be a function. Then we will call the sequence
$$ B_n := A_n^{(\nu(n))} $$
an *intertwined linear recursion*. In other words, $B_n$ is formed by intertwining the terms of a finite set of linear recursions, but the rule that decides which recursion to use for $B_n$ is more-or-less arbitrary. In particular, if $\nu$ is reasonably irregular, then $\sum_{n\ge1} B_nx^n$ will not be a rational function.

The recursions that I'm interested in also have the following *$n$'th root convergence property*:
$$ \text{The limit}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty} |B_n|^{1/n} \quad\text{exists}. $$

**Motivation**:Sequences of this sort with highly irregular $\nu$ appear in a paper of Hasselblatt and Propp [1]. Let $f:\mathbb{P}^N\to\mathbb{P}^N$ be a dominant rational map. Hasselblatt and Propp show that the associated degree sequence $\deg(f^n)$ is a generalized linear recursion, but that for many monomial maps in dimension $3$ and greater, the intertwining function $\nu$ depends on the decimal expansion of an irrational number, and hence $\sum_{n\ge1} \deg(f^n)x^n$ is not a rational function. On the other hand, it is known in general that the *dynamical degree* $$\delta(f):=\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigl(\deg(f^n)\bigr)^{1/n}$$ converges, i.e., $\deg(f^n)$ has the $n$'th root convergence property as defined above.

[1] Hasselblatt, Boris and Propp, James, Degree-growth of monomial maps,
*Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems* **27**(5) (2007), 1375--1397.

Comment: Your progressions of interest satisfy $B_n = a_{\nu(n)}n +b_{\nu(n)} \neq 0$ for all but finitely many $n$? In which case your limit exists and is 1?  Gerhard "Just Wanting To Make Sure" Paseman, 2017.07.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I'm not quite sure what you're asking? Are your $a_m$ and $b_m$ supposed to be arithmetic progressions. If so, then no, I don't  think that my $B_n$ have that form in general. The existence of the limit implies (and may be equivalent to?) the statement that the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of the $i$'th arithmetic sequence satisfies $|\lambda_1|=\cdots=|\lambda_k|$. The limit is this common value. There are lots of examples where the limit is not 1. But I don't feel that I've understood your comment/question.

Comment: I wanted to make abundantly clear that I know what you are talking about.  For your arithmetic progression $A^{(I)}$, I would have two corresponding numbers (initial term $b_I$ and common difference $a_I$) so that I could express the $n$th term as $a_In+b_I$.  If the $n$th term of your sequence $B$ is the $n$th term of one of your chosen progressions, then I have a hard time seeing your root limit, if it exists, as being other than 0 or 1, as B has subquadratic growth in $n$. (Also, the earlier subscripts are both $\nu(n)$, not $m$.) Gerhard "Or Maybe It's Something Else?" Paseman, 2017.07.10.

Comment: It's possible that your notion of arithmetic progression Is not the grade school notion, but a different sequence (with non constant difference between successive terms) defined perhaps through a recurrence relation.  It would help the nonspecialists in the audience if that notion of progression was made clear.  Gerhard "Progressing To A Greater Understanding" Paseman, 2017.07.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman My stupidity (and my apologies). I don't know why I wrote "arithmetic progression", when what I meant to write, as you guessed, was "linear recursion", i.e., sequences $A_n$ which, after some initial values, satisfy a linear recursion $A_{n+1} = a_0 A_n + a_1 A_{n-1} + \cdots + a_d A_{n-d}$ for some fixed integer $d$ and fixed coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_d$. I edited the question.

Comment: OK. I can see why B could have a root limit larger than 1.  However, it is not clear that the limit exists, as the value could "bounce" between different roots, or between 1 or 0 and a root.  To me, the picture is that B "bounces around" different progressions until it settles on 1.  If you could abbreviate one of your (hopefully more explicit than the present example involving $f$) examples of interest which has a root limit for this post, I would appreciate it.  Gerhard "Hopes To Lessen Shared Stupidity" Paseman, 2017.07.10.

Comment: Actually, reading over your earlier comment involving largest eigenvalues, I can build my own explicit example.  Thank you.  You might include the idea of that comment for other readers to chew on, along with your example using $f$. (Also, I'm going to edit your title to make your question clear.  Please revert if it becomes a problem.) Gerhard "Has Reached Some Comprehension Level" Paseman, 2017.07.10.